# WinPython Spyder can't see spyder-kernels in virtual environment

Tags: virtualenv, spyder

I have installed WinPython and want to use Spyder. I use pip and virtual environments. I have followed the instructions here [modular approach](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach). Everything works just dandy until the very last instruction "Start a new IPython console (in Spyder). All packages installed in your venv environment should be available there.".

It get error `Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.9.0 and < 1.10.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.`

But I installed spyder-kernals in my venv, I can literally see them there, I set the path the the python installed in the venv, everything should work, but it doesn't!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to ask to "C.A.M. Gerlach" if he has an update on the procedure: Spyder has evolved a bit with Spyder-4.

Answer (score 3):

I asked CAM Gerlach as suggested, and he spotted my error very quickly. The instructions at  [modular approach](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach) are correct except they say `pip install spyder-kernels==0.*` which I took literally. In fact as per the error message you need to use later versions, so I used `pip install spyder-kernels==1.10` and it fixed it.

Comment: and so what is your final configuration ? WinPython/Spyder/PyQt version ?

Comment: you saved me. thanks man~